# Intersection of linearly dependent sets

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Give an example of two linearly dependent sets in a vector space whose intersection in linearly independent.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I haven't tried. I mean i don't know how to start

Comment: Start out for example with a simple set that is linearly independent. The easiest I can think of would be a set containing one single vector, e.g. $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. How can you turn this into two linearly *dependent* sets, whose intersection is the original one?

Comment: We have to convert two linearly dependent sets in a vector space whose intersection is linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider, $A_1=\{(1,0),(0,1) ,(1,1)\}$ and $A_2=\{(1,0),(0,1) ,(1,2)\}\\ $ 
$A_1\cap A_2=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ which is linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Can you please explain it.

Comment: $A_1$ is a linearly dependent set in $\mathbb{R}^2 $ because dimension of $\mathbb{R}^2 $ over $\mathbb{R} $ is 2 and $A_1$ has three vectors, so they have to be dependent. Same is the case with $A_2$. But their intersection contains one vector in x-axis direction and another in y-axis direction. So the intersection is an independent set of vectors.